How to make my css buttons the same in mobile view
I made a button on my blog, on the laptop it looks normal
laptop view 
but on phone view it is vertical and to the side.
phone view  How do I make it look the same on both devices.


<div style="appearance: none;
       background-color: #a2826b; 
       border-radius: 0rem; 
       border: 0px;
       color: white; 
       cursor: pointer; 
       display: inline-block; 
       font-family: var(--system-font); 
       font-size: 18px; 
       font-weight: 700; 
       letter-spacing: 0em; 
       line-height: 1.45;
       margin-left: 250px; 
       outline: none; padding: 
       12px 20px; text-align: center; 
       text-decoration-color: initial; 
       text-decoration-line: none; 
       text-decoration-style: unset; 
       text-decoration-thickness: initial; 
       text-transform: none; 
       transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;">
  <a data-type="button" label="Shop On Amazon" style="color: white; 
      text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"> Shop On Amazon
    </a>
</div>




I'd start by removing margin-left: 250px; . Not sure what that is for, centering I assume but there are better methods available.

Please share more code so I can guide better

It is because of margin-left: 250px;. If you want that button in center you can just add flex property.


<div style=" display:flex;
       justify-content:center;
       align-items:center;">
  
  <div style="appearance: none;
       background-color: #a2826b; 
       border-radius: 0rem; 
       border: 0px;
       color: white; 
       cursor: pointer; 
       display: inline-block; 
       font-family: var(--system-font); 
       font-size: 18px; 
       font-weight: 700; 
       letter-spacing: 0em; 
       line-height: 1.45;
       outline: none; padding: 
       12px 20px; text-align: center; 
       text-decoration-color: initial; 
       text-decoration-line: none; 
       text-decoration-style: unset; 
       text-decoration-thickness: initial; 
       text-transform: none; 
       transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;">
  <a data-type="button" label="Shop On Amazon" style="color: white; 
      text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"> Shop On Amazon
    </a>
</div>
</div>




Thank You for the help, it worked. I'm grateful
